# One of the parameters is invalid as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

How To Fix One of the parameters is invalid as3?

1. First click bitnmap to show maps = OK
2. Maps + closebtnmap => show ,btn maps => hide
3. click closebtnmap to hide maps = OK
4. Second click btnmap to show maps = ERORR

**CODE**:

```
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var _webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();  
btnmap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addWebView);

function addWebView(e:MouseEvent):void  
{  
      _webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 170, 480,510);  
      _webView.stage = this.stage;  
      _webView.loadURL("https://goo.gl/maps/b6lMB");  
       btnclosemap.visible =true;
     btnclosemap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeWebView);  
}  

function closeWebView(e:MouseEvent):void  
{  
     _webView.stage = null;  
     _webView.dispose();
     btnclosemap.visible =false;
}
```

**ERROR** :

> ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
>           at flash.media::StageWebView/set viewPort()
>           at sanggaluri_fla::plokasi_27/addWebView()[sanggaluri_fla.plokasi_27::frame1:29]

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: While it's not the solution to your error,  you should move your `btnclosemap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeWebView)` outside of the `addWebView` method

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
 at flash.media::StageWebView/set viewPort()
 at sanggaluri_fla::plokasi_27/addWebView()[sanggaluri_fla.plokasi_27::frame1:29]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely because in the `closeWebView` method, you dispose the `StageWebView` called `_webView`.

So now, when you click a second time and `addWebView` runs, you try to set it's viewport, but the web view has been disposed and so it throws the error.

To make it work,  create a new `StageWebView` inside your `addWebView` method.

So:

```
var _webView:StageWebView; //don't instantiate it here  

btnmap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addWebView);    
btnclosemap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeWebView); 

function addWebView(e:MouseEvent):void  
{  
      if(!_webView){
          _webView = new StageWebView(); //Create a new one here if it doesn't exist / is null
      }
      _webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 170, 480,510);  
      _webView.stage = this.stage;  
      _webView.loadURL("https://goo.gl/maps/b6lMB");  
       btnclosemap.visible =true; 
}  

function closeWebView(e:MouseEvent):void  
{  
     _webView.stage = null;  
     _webView.dispose();
     _webView = null; //make it null so you know it's been disposed
     btnclosemap.visible =false;
}
```

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: FIX...Thank you... :) (y)